# submit時、同一のキーを含む項目が既に追加されていますエラー発生

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

至急解決したいです。

環境：Asp.Net MVC4(cshtml)

submitで、viewにバインドしてるviewmodelをコンロトーラーへpostしたいのですが
「同一のキーを含む項目が既に追加されています。 」として
'/' アプリケーションサーバー エラーが発生します。

何が悪いのかわからず、どなたかご教授頂けないでしょうか？

＜cshtml＞

```
@model 名前空間.ViewModels.サンプルViewModel
…略…
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "コントローラー名", FormMethod.Post))
{
    …略…

    <td><input type="submit" value="登録"/></td>

}
```

＜コントローラー＞

```
// 初期表示
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string dType)
{
    var ViewModel = new サンプルViewModel();

    …(ViewModelにもろもろセット)…

    return View(ViewModel);
｝

// 登録
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(サンプルViewModel vm)
{
    …略…
}
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: エラーメッセージの通りで、「同一のキーを含む項目が既に追加されて」いるとできないような処理をあなたのコードが(おそらく「…略…」の中のどこかで)無理にやろうとしているからサーバエラーになっているわけです。一番肝心なところを略されては「何が悪いのか」を具体的に指摘することはできません。(多分データベースへのINSERT処理あたりだと思いますが。)その部分が何をしているのか、略さずに示すようにしてください。

Comment: すみません、自己解決しました。
view内でデバッグ用に設けていた同一内容のinputタグが
ModelStateのkey、valueのペアセットの重複エラーとなっていたようです。
デバッグ用を削除したら無事POSTされ、Viewmodelも引き継がれました。
以上お騒がせ致しました。

Comment: なるほど、データベースではなく、Model内のkey重複の問題だったようですね。解決できた今、ご質問内容を見返して、この質問だけを読んだ読者が(読者はあなたのコードについて、質問にある内容以外は何も知らないわけです)そのような問題を発見できるだろうかどうかよく考えてみてください。今後ご質問を書かれる際の参考になるだろうと思います。

Comment: 申し訳ございません。以後、読者側の立場になって投稿するよう努めます。

Comment: 責めているのではなく改善のきっかけにしていただきたいと言う意味でのコメントですので、あまり恐縮なさらないでいただければと思います。実際問題として、原因がわからない時にどこまでの情報を質問に含めれば良いのかは難しいですから。今後機会があれば何らのお役に立てることを願っております。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。確かにあの情報だけでは少なすぎで、みなさまからのヒントやご回答が頂けなかったのは事実です。今後解決を急ぐ為にも、出来る範囲でなるべく詳細な情報を提示するよう努めます。

Answer (score 1):

すみません、自己解決しました。

view 内でデバッグ用に設けていた同一内容の input タグが、ModelState の key, value のペアセットの重複エラーとなっていたようです。

デバッグ用を削除したら無事 POST され、Viewmodel も引き継がれました。

---

*この投稿は [@user30436 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/49494/submit%e6%99%82-%e5%90%8c%e4%b8%80%e3%81%ae%e3%82%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%82%92%e5%90%ab%e3%82%80%e9%a0%85%e7%9b%ae%e3%81%8c%e6%97%a2%e3%81%ab%e8%bf%bd%e5%8a%a0%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%be%e3%81%99%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e7%99%ba%e7%94%9f#comment51541_49494) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*